# Autocomplete performance and private "magic search"

Tags: javascript, search, architecture, autocomplete, client-side

Poor performance of autocomplete fields reduces their usefulness. If the client-side implementation has to call an endpoint that does heavy db lookup, the response time can easily get frustrating.

One neat approach comes from [AWS Case Study: IMDb](http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/imdb/). It used to come with a diagram (no longer available), but in a nutshell a prediction tree would be generated and stored for every combination that can resolve in a meaningful way. E.g. resolutions for `sta` would include `Star Wars, Star Trek, Sylvester Stallone` which will be stored, but `stb` will not resolve to anything meaningful and will not be stored.

> To get the lowest possible latency, all possible results are
>   pre-calculated with a document for every combination of letters in
>   search. Each document is pushed to Amazon Simple Storage Service
>   (Amazon S3) and thereby to Amazon CloudFront, putting the documents
>   physically close to the users. The theoretical number of possible
>   searches to calculate is mind-boggling—a 20-character search has 23 x
>   1030 combinations—but in practice, using IMDb's authority on movie and
>   celebrity data can reduce the search space to about 150,000 documents,
>   which Amazon S3 and Amazon CloudFront can distribute in just a few
>   hours. IMDb creates indexes in several languages with daily updates
>   for datasets of over 100,000 movie and TV titles and celebrity names.

How would one achieve a similarly performant experience be achieved with private data? E.g. autocompleting client names, job ids, invoice numbers... Storing different documents/decision trees for separate users sounds expensive, especially if some of the data (client names?) could be available for multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

You right that such workload requires some special optimizations.

You can use ready search engine like [Apache lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (wich is REST API wrapper for lucene)

This engine optimized for full text searches and can work with private data.

**Work steps:**

1. Install solr (or lucene)
2. Design schema for storing information (what fields and what types of searchs you need)
3. Load data into it ( via bach operations or on update basis)
4. Query searches based on solrs query language (similar to google search).
   In this place you could add special restrictions based on user_id or any over parameter in addition to original user query. So private data wouldn't mess between users.

Answer (score 0):

I actually agree with CGI.  The best solution is a 3rd party search engine.  Anything else is trying to build your own search engine.  I'm really not sure what the hardware at your disposal by your post so i'll give a possible solution for a lowbrow if all you got is LAMP hosting.

So in your PHP code you would make a query string like:

```
$qstr = "SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE `name` like '%".$search."%' ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 0,100";
```

Than increment the popularity column for every record that is found via the "search engine."
On the front end (Lets say your using Dojo) you could do something like...

```
<script>
   require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/domReady!"], function (on, dom, xhr) {
       on(dom.byId('txtSearch'), "change", function(evt) {
           if (typeof searchCheck !== undefined) clearTimeout(searchCheck);
           searchCheck = setTimeout(function() { //keep from flooding XHR
               xhr("fetch-json-results.php", {
                  handleAs: "json"
               }).then(function(data){
                  //update txtSearch combo store
               });
           }, 500);
       });
   });
</script>
<input id="txtSearch" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" data-dojo-props="intermediateChanges:true">
```

This would be a low tech low budget (LAMP) equiv answer.

Comment: What I meant by "increment popularity column for every record that is found" is when the user selects that item out of the list of the search results.

Comment: And i'm being scatter brained... Also just push your results to the combo box's data store don't replace existing results.  Let the widget do the rest of the narrowing down.  You also want to tweak the timeout and the number of results returned.  I just wrote this off-the-cuff.