# Typeahead POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax, typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I have been trying to use [this issue code](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/542) as a way to do post instead of the default, get without ruining the nice features of typeahead. Except I can't seem to figure it out, I struggled enough to figure out this but now I haven't a clue.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? My code with commenting out the new code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Submit Deal test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- for twitter typeahead bundle -->
    <script src="js/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<?php /*authenticate the user is going from submitdeal.php*/
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = 10;
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function(){
        var brands;

        brands = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.num); },
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: 'brands.php?query=%QUERY'
                /*url: 'brands.php'
                // since we use POST, the URL never changes so we simulate a different URL for each query
                // for the typeahead internal request cache.
                replace: function (url, uriEncodedQuery){
                    return url + "#" + uriEncodedQuery; // the part after the hash is not sent to the server
                },
                beforeSend: function (jqXhr, settings){
                    jqXhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    settings.type = 'POST';
                    settings.hasContent = true;
                    settings.data = $.param({beneficiary: queryInput.val()});
                },*/
                }
        });

        brands.initialize();

        $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
            displayKey: 'name',
            source: brands.ttAdapter()
        });

    });//]]>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="begin typing the brand" autocomplete="off">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347121/update-json-on-every-keyup-for-twitter-typeahead/